# TypeError on jQuery click function

Tags: javascript, jquery

since any wordpress- or plugin-update one of my order-buttons dosen't work anymore.

Just in safari... Chrome & Firefox is still Ok.

I get this error:

```
TypeError: Can only call HTMLElement.insertAdjacentElement on instances of HTMLElement

insertAdjacentElement - jquery.js:2958
```

This is the affected function:

```
$("#order-now").click(function(){

    var countEle = halsband[2].length;
    if (halsband[3] != "keins"){
        countEle++;
    }
    if (countEle == 7){
        $("#max-anzahl").css("display", "block");
        $(".modal-ov").css("display", "block");
    }else{
        letsOrder();
    }
});
```

The error just appears when the function "letsOrder" is called:

```
function letsOrder(){
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>",
        data: {
            'action': 'products_to_cart',
            'halsband_id': halsband_id,
            'halsband_var_id': halsband_var_id,
            'halsband_var_name': halsband_var_name,
            'name': halsband[2],
            'buchstabe_id': buchstabe_id,
            'buchstabe_eins_var_id': buchstabe_eins_var_id,
            'buchstabe_eins_var_name': buchstabe_eins_var_name,
            'buchstabe_zwei_var_id': buchstabe_zwei_var_id,
            'buchstabe_zwei_var_name': buchstabe_zwei_var_name,
            'buchstabe_drei_var_id': buchstabe_drei_var_id,
            'buchstabe_drei_var_name': buchstabe_drei_var_name,
            'buchstabe_vier_var_id': buchstabe_vier_var_id,
            'buchstabe_vier_var_name': buchstabe_vier_var_name,
            'buchstabe_fuenf_var_id': buchstabe_fuenf_var_id,
            'buchstabe_fuenf_var_name': buchstabe_fuenf_var_name,
            'buchstabe_sechs_var_id': buchstabe_sechs_var_id,
            'buchstabe_sechs_var_name': buchstabe_sechs_var_name,
            'charm_id': charm_id,
            'anhaenger': anhaenger
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(errorThrown){
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });

    $("#cart-success").css("display", "block");
    $(".modal-ov").css("display", "block");
}
```

All the data options should be normal strings.

I would be grateful for any idea!

Many thanks in advance,
Marvin

---

EDIT:

This is the full error:

```
insertAdjacentElement, jquery.js:3:24987
e, jquery.js:3:24987
dc, jquery.js:3:24872
dc, jquery.js:3:24896
param, query.js:3:25234
ajax, jquery.js:3:21049
letsOrder, konfigurator.js:519
(anonyme Funktion), konfigurator.js:464
dispatch, jquery-latest.min.js:2:8441
handle, jquery-latest.min.js:2:5144
```

[This](http://www.hundehalsband-mit-namen.net/konfigurator/) is the affected website. The error appears when you click on "Halsband bestellen" directly under the price (Just in Safari)

Comment: Your problem is somewhere else. Check the error, it's not related to this code.

Comment: Does safari's web developer tool console allow you to see a stack trace when an error is issued? Because as the previous comment says, nothing in the code you've posted should cause an `insertAdjacentElement` to be required

Comment: What is version of jQuery where error is logged?

Comment: `insertAdjacentElement` does not appear in any version of `jQuery.js`

Comment: if you type `jQuery.fn.jquery` in the console, what does it return?

Comment: jQuery.fn.jquery return this: "1.12.4"

Comment: [This](http://www.hundehalsband-mit-namen.net/konfigurator/) is the affected website. The error appears when you click on "Halsband bestellen" directly under the price (Just in Safari)

Comment: insertAdjacentElement does not appear, at all, in any javascript on that site - clearly something else gets loaded if and only if Safari is detected - you also have two versions of jQUery loaded, 1.11.1 and 1.12.4 - neither of which have any reference to taht function

Answer (score 0):

The error was caused by the plugin "Page scroll to id"... (the simplest plugin of all).

Many thanks for your quick answers! Otherwise i would still search in my own js-file.

Marvin